# .net dll not found intermittently with local system account

Tags: .net, dll, openxml

I have a .Net tool that generates a spreadsheet using the Open XML SDK. This has worked fine for months. Suddenly, I'm getting this error, intermittently:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml, Version=2.0.5022.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
DocumentFormat.OpenXml, Version=2.0.5022.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml, Version=2.0.5022.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
File name: 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml, Version=2.0.5022.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
   at ConvertXMLtoExcel.ExcelGenerator.CreatePackage(String filePath)
   at ConvertXMLtoExcel.Program.Main(String[] args)


System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

I've verified that the DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll file is in the GAC. When I run the tool from the command prompt manually, it works 100% of the time. It works 100% of the time on my development machine (Windows 7).

However, when the command is invoked by a web service (Apache -> PHP -> exec) it fails roughly 50% of the time with the above exception.

I've spent far too long looking into this problem to have come up with nothing.

The best possible explanations I've read suggest 32/64 bit compatibility problems or DLL missing from GAC. But these would result in 100% failure right? Even when logged in as user?

I've run sys internals ProcMon over the process and captured it both succeeding and failing. They profiles are quite different. If I filter the list by "Load Image", I can see they start out exactly the same, until a point.

The succeeding one loads "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorwks.dll", the failing one doesn't, and it loads "C:\WINDOWS\system32\faultrep.dll" instead.

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: It fails to find a required DLL, an unmanaged one.  It should be visible in the ProcMon log, you should see it search through the PATH for the missing DLL.